# Verifying proof for the following question

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

I wanted to check my proof if it is correct or not. Using these field axioms:

(i)Trichotomy Property:  Exactly one of $x<y$, $y<x$, or $x=y$ hold.

(ii)Transitivity: if $x<y$ and $y<z$ (which we could write in shorthand as $x<y<z$), then $x<z$.

(iii)If $x<y$ then $x+z < y+z$.

(iv) If $x<y$ and $z>0$ then $xz<yz$.

> - (A1) Addition is commutative
> - (A2) Addition is associative
> - (A3) Addition has a neutral element $0$
> - (A4) Any element has an additive inverse
> - (A5) Multiplication is commutative
> - (A6) Multiplication is associative
> - (A7) Multiplication has a neutral element $1$
> - (A8) Any non-zero element has a multiplicative inverse
> - (A9) Multiplication distributes over addition

1. Prove that for all $a,\, b,\, c\in\mathbb{R}$, if $a<b$ and $c<0$ then $bc < ac$.

Since $a<b$, by (A4), we have that $$
0 = a + (-a) < b + (-a) = b - a.$$ 
Since $b - a > 0$ and $c < 0$, then $c(b-a) < 0$. By (A9), this is equivalent to $cb-ca<0$. By (A3), $$
cb=cb-ca+ca<0+ca=ca.$$
Thus $cb<ca$.

Comment: "Since b−a>0 and c<0, then c(b−a)<0" Explain why you say this. what axiom are you using? (Are you assuming that $0(b-a) = 0$?  Why do you know *that*?)

Answer (score 0):

"Since b−a>0 and c<0, then c(b−a)<0"

Why do you state this. Either this is what you wish to prove, or (and I suspect this) you are using  iv) but not saying so.

So you should say so.

Since $(b-a)> 0$ and $c < 0$ then by iv) $c(b-a) < 0\cdot (b-a)$

But notice. You *don't* have an axiom that $0\cdot x = 0$(!!!!)

You have to prove that.

Hint 1: $0d = (0+0)d$

Hint 2: $-0d$ must exist.

....

Once you prove that you have

$c(b-a) <0$

So by A9 $c(b-a) = c(b+(-a)) = cb +c(-a)$

So $cb + c(-a) < 0$ and

....

Now we need to prove $c(-a) = -ca$.

Hint: $c(-a) + ca = c(-a + a)$.

...

Now we have $cb - ca <0$ and ... you can finish your proof.

Answer (score -1):

Your proof has a gap.  How do you know that $b-a \gt 0 \land c \lt 0 \Rightarrow c(b-a) \lt 0$?  I'm not saying you're wrong -- I'm just saying you haven't yet proved it.

**Edit to add:**

**Lemma:**  If $c \lt 0 \land x \lt y, \text{ then } xc \gt yc$.

**Proof:**  $c+(-c) = 0 \land c \lt 0 \Rightarrow -c \gt 0$.  (Use property (iii), adding $-c$ to both sides of the inequality.)

Thus, $-xc \lt -yc$.  Add $xc + yc$ to both sides:  $yc  \lt xc$ and the Lemma is proved.

Comment: Could it be by (ii)? @Robert Shore

Comment: You've obviously put effort into this, so I've edited my answer to fill in a proof for your gap.

Comment: Thank you for your help in this process @Robert Shore. I added the lemma and proof after the −>0∧<0⇒(−)<0 statement.

Comment: I'm a nitpicker.  How do you know that $x(-c) = -xc$?  And um... isn't the lemma the same thing as the question?  Just with $a,b$ being replaced with $x,y$? And $bc < ac$ being replaced with $xc > yc$?

Comment: A fair point.  $x(-c)+xc=x(-c+c)=x0=0 \Rightarrow x(-c)=-xc.$

Comment: can we say by A9 for your last point about c(-a) = -ca? @fleablood

Comment: Not until you prove that $-a = -1 \cdot a$.

Comment: It's a pain in the ass but you cant assume anything.  If I were to do it my way I'd note that "subtraction" as an operation has not actually been defined at all!  $a-b$ is *notation* for $a+(-b)$.  I'd prove if we define that as an operation then it distributes over multiplication and as a *immediate* consequence $c*0=c(0-0)=c*0 -c*0=0$ and that $c(-a) = c(0-a)=c0-ca = 0-ca = -ca$.  But I'd have to *prove* $c(a-b) = ca -cb$ first.  Maybe I'd do it that way.